# Flutter - BloC Cubit function doesn't emitting state

Tags: android, flutter, bloc

I'm creating a Flutter application. I'm added a BloC to my project for management state.
I created a list with data. And I want to add item to ListView manually with button 'Add'.

I'm wrote a code:

**My Item Cubit**

```
class ItemCubit extends Cubit<List<Item>> {
  ItemCubit() : super([]);

  void addItem(item){
    state.add(item);
    emit(state);
  }
}
```

**Page of Items with Provider**:

```
class SearchPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: BlocProvider(
        create: (_) => ItemCubit(),
        child: Search(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I call the BlocBuilder in Stateless Widget like this:

```
body: BlocBuilder<MarketCubit, List<Market>>(
            builder: (context, items) => TabBarView(...))
```

So when I call my function from state:

```
Item item = Item(1, 'Item 1');


ElevatedButton(onPressed:(){
  context.read<ItemCubit>().addItem(item);
 }, child: Text('Add Item')),
```

The ListView doesn't updating. What's problem?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create new variable, add them to the new variable list, update your new variable list item to it, emit the data with the new variable. this is how i got it working.

```
late List<ServicesExpensesList> newList = <ServicesExpensesList>[];
    state.utilityDataList.forEach((element) {
      newList.add(element);
    });
    newList.insert(0, utilityData);
    newList.sort((a, b) => b.createdAt.compareTo(a.createdAt));
    emit(state.copyWith(
      utilityDataList: newList,
      status: state.status == BlocStateStatus.success
          ? BlocStateStatus.updated
          : BlocStateStatus.success,
    ))
```

Comment: this answer worked in my case. I was using List.from(state.oldListPlusChangeOnIndex); but it wasn't emitting...

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are just adding the item to the state and re-emitting the same (modified) list. Bloc will essentially check the value of the state object to see if it is a new object when you call emit(), if it is the 'same list' as the last state, it will do nothing. It is confusing because even though you are adding a new value to the list, it is still the same object in a sense, just with a new value.

So there should be an easy fix if you just create a new list instead of modifying the original one and emit that.

For example, this should fix the issue:

```
emit([...state, newValue])
```

or

```
final newList = List.from(state)..add(newValue);
emit(newList);
```

(I had trouble finding in the bloc documentation where this is explained, but there are a number of issue threads where it is discussed -https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2374)

Essentially, the state should be 'immutable', so if you are going to emit a new state, you should actually create a new instance of whatever you are going to emit. The way I typically use the state is to have a class with final fields for whatever state the cubit is tracking, and a copyWith method that makes it easy to create a new instance with any modified fields:

```
YourCubitState{
    final List stateList;
    final otherField;

    const YourCubitState({
        this.stateList = [], 
        this.otherField,
    }); 

    YourCubitState copyWith({
        List? stateList,
        otherField,
    }) => 
        YourCubitState(
           stateList: stateList ?? this.stateList,
           otherField: otherField ?? this.otherField,
        );   

}
```

Maybe that is unnecessary if the state is just a single list, but if you find yourself wanting to add properties to the state, that is a good pattern to follow.

Comment: Thanks) But it doesn't work for me. I think the problem not in this.

Comment: the 'same object' statement is gold, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

ItemCubit class superclass not holding your state. You should manage yourself states. So, what I say, I'm saying create list variable inside ItemCubit class and every call addItem method add item to this list and emit this list.

Your Cubit class should be as below;

```dart
abstract class ItemState {
  const ItemState();
}
```

```dart
class ItemInitial extends ItemState {
  const ItemInitial();
}
```

```dart
class ItemStateUpdatedList extends ItemState {
  const ItemStateUpdatedList({required this.list});

  final List<Item> list;
}
```

```dart
class ItemCubit extends Cubit<ItemState> {
  ItemCubit() : super(const ItemInitial());
  
  final List<Item> myItemList = [];

  void addItem(item){
    myItemList.add(item);
    emit(ItemStateUpdatedList(list: myItemList));
  }
}
```

```dart
body: BlocBuilder<ItemCubit, ItemState>(
          builder:(context, state) {
            if(state is ItemStateUpdatedList){
              final list = state.list;
              return TabBarView(...);
            }
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          },
)
```

Comment: Thanks. It's work. But ListView doesn't updating.

Comment: In order to understand that Cubit's state has been updated, the instance needs to change. You should use an abstract class structure in this way. (updated my answer)

Comment: Salih Can, thanks! I'm runned your script. But state is ItemStateUpdatedList return false. This script returned SizedBox.shrink(); What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @user467566 You can try with DartPad: https://dartpad.dev/?id=51ef214e36ced547ecbe3a317d060899

Answer (score 1):

Cubit or block is a **state change emitter**, and since state is a set of attributes and properties then, the key thing here is the ability of Cubit and Bloc to figure out that something has been changed with properties or attributes otherwise will not emit new state.

this is how it works for me:

```
abstract class ObjectListState extends Equatable {
`final List<String> items;
 const ObjectListState(this.items);
 }

class ObjectListStateInitial extends ObjectListState {
 const ObjectListStateInitail(super.items);
  @override
   List<Object> get props => [];
 }

class ObjectListStateItemAdded extends ObjectListState {
  final String item;
  final List<String> items;
  ObjectListStateItemAdded( this.item, this.items) : super(items){
   items.add(item);
   }

   @override
  List<Object> get props => [item,items];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A had the same problem, I just add a Random Number to props

"List< Object> get props => [cbspsrListadePalabras, Random().nextInt(10000)];"

Comment: This will work almost always but should not be advised. This approach may cause too many rebuilds.

Answer (score 0):

If the same state is emitting you can just add `identityHashCode(this)` in your state class:

```
class OrderError extends OrderConfirmationState with EquatableMixin {

  OrderError({});


  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [identityHashCode(this)];
}
Use this package - https://pub.dev/packages/equatable
```