# Flutter - How to add item to ListView dynamically using BloC

Tags: android, flutter, bloc

I have a small Flutter application. In this app I have a route to Stateless widget from Stateful widget. And **setState(...)** doesn't work in Stateless widget. Also **Navigator.push(...)** doesn't route to Stateful widgets.

I want to add items to ListView dynamically using 'Add Item' button. How can I do it using BloC? Where I can find the neccessary documentation? And can you show me small part of code?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't want a ready code block. You should try to do this scenario and ask if you can't. You can use these docs to make: https://bloclibrary.dev/ 

Comment: I tried to do this. But I can't to do it. I created a theme for this, but I'm didn't get an answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70411724/flutter-bloc-cubit-function-doesnt-emitting-state

Comment: I will look into it and prepare an answer.